# How can I know the absolute path of a running process? on solaris

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, process, ps

this is the command to view the process path on Linux

```
ps -auxwe | grep 24466    ( 24466 is only example )
```

but please advice is it possible  to view the path of running process on Solaris

if yes what the ps syntax for Solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pwdx in solaris and linux.

pwdx `<pid_number>`

example:

```
pwdx $$
25711:  /export/home/pippo
```

Comment: `pwdx` emits the *current working directory* of a process.  Per [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pwdx.1.html): "pwdx - report current working directory of a process"  Per [the Solaris man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/pwdx-1.html#scrolltoc): "pwdx Print the current working directory of each process."

Answer (score 3):

> How can I know the absolute path of a running process?

If by "absolute path" you mean the full path of the running binary, this works on my installed copy of Solaris 11:

```
pmap PID | grep -v ':' | head 1 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Replace `PID` with the the process id of the process you're interested in.

`pmap` emits the address map of the process, including the full path of the source file for the mapping.  This includes the actual binary, which is the first *mapping* line of the output.  The first line of the output contains the process id and the process arguments.  Note that the process arguments are not sufficient to fully identify the full path to the running executable file.  The first few lines of actual address space mappings are mappings from the actual executing binary, listed with the full, absolute path of the binary.

Unfortunately, you need read access to the process map to get that information.  I don't know of any way to get what you're looking for without having that access.

Edit:  There's also `/proc/[PID]/path/a.out` on Solaris 11, which is a soft link to the actual binary:

In bash:

```
bash-4.1$ readlink /proc/$$/path/a.out
/usr/bin/bash
```

Note that `/proc/$$/path/a.out` is better than `/proc/self/path/a.out`:

```
bash-4.1$ readlink /proc/self/path/a.out
/usr/bin/readlink
```

Unfortunatly, if you don't have access to the process map via `pmap`, you likely won't have access to `/proc/[PID]/path/a.out`, as the permissions on `/proc/[PID]/path` for my Solaris 11 install are all 500 - only the owner and root have read and execute permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

/usr/ucb/ps auxwwww | grep 6851 worked for me on SunOS servername01 5.10 Generic_147440-25 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490